# android combine array to the loop

Tags: android

I created an android working with default listview. Now I have 2 arrays declares as below. Please help to solve this issue. Thanks!

```
String[] item_index = {"1","2","3","4"};
String[] item_name = {"Bacon","Egg","Cheese","Tomato" };
String[] item_price = {"$2.50","$3.00","$2.70","$2.80" };
String[] item_barcode = {"T1","T2","T3","T4"};

I want to show the resule using **for loop** as below
 1. T1-Bacon ($2.50)
 2. T2-Egg ($3.00)
 3. T3-Cheese ($2.70)
 4. T4-Tomato ($2.80)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is that your all array have same size at all the time?

Comment: Thanks. Yes all my array the same size and all the time.

Comment: Ok then all the answer of given question are correct.

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: Thank you. All my array size the same. One more question if I want to get this result and keep to array adapter for my listview. How to do?               
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,.....?????....)

Comment: Yes you need to set all the output in one String array and you set that in your String of ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Like this way : ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSongTitles);

Comment: I have updated my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202069/6238866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is `immutable` whereas `StringBuffer` and `StringBuider` are `mutable` classes. StringBuffer is **`thread safe and synchronized`** whereas StringBuilder is not, thats why `StringBuilder is more faster than StringBuffer`. String concat + operator internally uses StringBuffer or `StringBuilder` class. So it is quite good to use StringBuilder to append string.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String[] item_index = {"1","2","3","4"};
String[] item_name = {"Bacon","Egg","Cheese","Tomato" };
String[] item_price = {"$2.50","$3.00","$2.70","$2.80" };
String[] item_barcode = {"T1","T2","T3","T4"};
String[] ansValue = new String[item_index.length];
for(int i=0;i<item_index.length;i++){
    s.setLength(0);
    s.append(item_index[i]);
    s.append(" . ");
    s.append(item_barcode[i]);
    s.append(" -");
    s.append(item_name[i]);
    s.append("(");
    s.append(item_name[i]);
    s.append(")");
    ansValue[i]=s.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ansValue);
```

Comment: Yes that answer is beautiful. I’ll try this in my project and also lets you know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes today I'm continuing my project. Now It's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @KhoemVichet If its work fine then pls accept the my answer.

Comment: Yes now I'm using your code in my project. Which button lets me click or do accept your answer.

Comment: @KhoemVichet Yes You can accept as well as also upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

if all array size are same use this

```
for(int i=0;i<item_index.length;i++)
{
Systrem.out.println(item_index[i]+" . "+item_barcode[i]+" -"+item_name[i]+"("+item_price[i]+")");
}
```

Edit:

```
ArrayList<String> items= new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<item_index.length;i++)
{
items.add(item_index[i]+" . "+item_barcode[i]+" -"+item_name[i]+"("+item_price[i]+")");
}
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Note: Make sure that all are have same size. Otherwise you will get ArrayindexOutofBounds exception.

Comment: Thank you. All my array size the same. One more question if I want to get this result and keep to array adapter for my listview. How to do?

Comment: final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,.....?????....)

Comment: that case you create only list add this value in list  then use array adapter.

Answer (score 1):

A bit naive approach but will work for arrays with same size:

```
String[] item_index = {"1","2","3","4"};
String[] item_name = {"Bacon","Egg","Cheese","Tomato" };
String[] item_price = {"$2.50","$3.00","$2.70","$2.80" };
String[] item_barcode = {"T1","T2","T3","T4"};

public void printer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < item_index.length; i++) {
        String line = String.format("%d. %s-%s (%s)", i + 1, item_barcode[i], item_name[i], item_price[i]);
        // print or push to view
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

If there is a chance that arrays sizes will be not the same you can try to use something like that:

```
public String defaultStringAtPosIfNull(String[] arr, int pos, String defaultString) {
    if (pos >= arr.length) {
        return defaultString;
    }
    return arr[pos] != null ? arr[pos] : defaultString;
}
```

and call it in String.format:`defaultStringAtPosIfNull(item_barcode, i, "(empty)")` instead calling `item_barcode[i]` directly.

Answer (score 1):

A better coding approach would be having an `Item` class

```
public class Item {
    public String name;
    public String price;
    public String barcode;
    public String index;

    public Item(String name, String price, String barcode, String index) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.index + ". " + this.barcode + "-" + this.name + " (" + this.price + ") "; 
    }
}
```

And then just have

```
for(Item item : items) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Lets me this this procedure.

Comment: @KhoemVichet Upvote the answers since they re all valid and mark one as correct. We took our time to help you :)

Comment: Yes I’ll do it. Thanks for your help.